# Can I make a Matrix Fieldtype and put in a row another Matrix fieldtype that contain file fieldtype?

Tags: matrix

I need to make a Matrix fieldtype where i have:
1 Column -> Text field -> Label: Chapter
2 Column -> Matrix -> 1 Column -> Text field -> Label: Slide
                   -> 2 Column -> File field -> file

I need to do it like a PowerPoint slideshow where Members can make a new slideshow with an entry in a channel "presentation", and add "chapter 1" -> add slide 1, add slide 2, add slide 3 ... Then add "chapter 2" -> add slide 4, add slide 5, add slide 6 ...

Can you help me to understad how?

Answer (score 1):

If you're needing to have multiple slides per Matrix row, why not use Assets to upload multiple files for each row? You'd have an Assets column in your Matrix to handle that.

Comment: I've to try it. so i can add multiple file for each row?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst you may be able to cobble this together using something like [Nolan](https://github.com/iainurquhart/Nolan), I would instead recommend using two separate channels - one for Presentations and another for Slides, then use [Playa](http://pixelandtonic.com/playa/) to pull in the relevant slides into a presentation. This will give you much more flexibility (multiple custom fields/matrices per-slide) and will probably perform better too.

Comment: I've tried to use Nolan, but i can configure only text fieldtype. I haven't Playa, and it's a bit expansive. And i think that with Playa make a new presentation for a member become a little more difficult. The best could be that when a member post an entry (new presentation) has only one Matrix fieldtype which in second column has a second Matrix fieldtype configured whit file fieldtype. So each new entry is a new presentation.